# How to simulate keyboard play/pause command?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to pause what's playing in the **background** on the **OS** (music, youtube...), like when we click on the play/pause key, so I can lunch my alarm sound from my google extension.

Is there a way to do that using **Javascript**?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to pause things that are playing outside your site? It's impossible

Comment: You're looking for simulating a multimedia keys (`VK_MEDIA_STOP` in your case). As I know, there's no way to do this from chrome extention either.

Comment: Thank you for saving me time, I look around and found nothing indeed.